# Running a python program after setting the execute bit in Python 3

Tags: python

I was going through [Google's Python instructions](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/set-up#download-google-python-exercises) and it quotes:

> The commands above are the simplest way to run python programs. If the
>   "execute bit" is set on a .py file, it can be run by name without
>   having to type "python" first. Set the execute bit with the "chmod"
>   command like this:

Where it proceeds to give me this code to run on my terminal:

```
~/google-python-exercises$ chmod +x hello.py
~/google-python-exercises$ ./hello.py   ## now can run it as ./hello.py
Hello World
```

However when I type in `./hello.py`, I get:

[image]

So is this something to do with me using **Python 3** when this could be a command for **Python 2**?

**EDIT**

I just realised that this can only be run on a Linux/Mac. How does one go about doing this on a Windows?

Comment: `python hello.py` assuming the python path is in your environment variables

Comment: @JamesBuck Yeah, I'm aware of executing the program in that manner, but I just wanted to know how to simply execute it with a `./hello.py`

Comment: Then search for `Default Programs` in windows and then associate the .py extension with python.exe.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala: Well, just to be clear, `./hello.py` is never going to work (because it looks like trying to launch a program named `.` with the switch `/hello.py`. On Windows, you'd just do `hello.py` or `.\hello.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to associate the file extension with Python properly. This should happen by default if you install system wide (which requires administrator privileges), but if you're using a third party distribution, it's not guaranteed, and it may require a reboot even so.

For more details running Python on Windows, see the [Python on Windows docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html). It looks like if you omitted the launcher from your Python install, it won't have registered the file extensions; it may be worth reinstalling properly to fix that.

Otherwise, if you can't get file extension associations working, just run:

```
python hello.py
```

or starting with 3.3 and later, you can use:

```
py hello.py
```

which lets you provide an argument to `py.exe` to change which installed version of Python to use (if desired).

You wouldn't use `./hello.py` on Windows at all, because that's the wrong directory separator (Windows sometimes allows forward slashes, but in DOS prompts, that looks like trying to launch a program named `.` with the switch `/hello.py`). You'd use plain `hello.py` (Windows always searches the current working directory) or `.\hello.py` if you want to be explicit.

Comment: But I have downloaded and installed *python* from the official website.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala: If you didn't install Python for the system, only per-user, then it won't have installed the launcher or registered the file associations. You'd need to run the installer as an Administrator and install the launcher to register the associations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as the first line in `hello.py`?

something like:
`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: OP is running on Windows, shebang lines don't do much there (though with the 3.3+ launcher, they're read to determine the default version of Python to launch for that script).

Comment: Oops, you are right @ShadowRanger. I'm not familiar with how it works on windows.